# Address line CONTORTS after login

Tags: asp.net, http, url, ip-address

We have an application where the URL occasionally "contorts" after a user logs in. Does anyone have any idea what causes this?  Has anyone ever SEEN this?

**Here is what the address line looks like when this happens:**

```
http://OurServer:Port/%28X%281%29F%28QlhJfSuWq05cmw4xBOiB323Oh98gGNzpcPeF429xqbdYsmUMNGxKKtrYJBXuc6zK-z5RaOudUAzL-Qquha_7S-yUWF6nT230pRU8RfbS-m-S1_14BYQXY9aObiG9uKmpmG6hQAU8P6U347emEVMG4CPZfEA1%29%29/Forms/Default.aspx
```

**Here is what it looks like BEFORE login:**

```
http://OurServer:Port/Forms/LoginLogout.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
```

...or

```
http://OurServer:Port/Forms/LoginLogout.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fForms%2fDefault.aspx
```

**Here is what it SHOULD look like AFTER login:**

```
http://OurServer:Port/Forms/Default.aspx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net puts the session identifier in the URL when the browser does not accept cookies (usual place for the session id). So the reason you are seeing this extra information (sessionid) in the URL on occasion is when browser does not accept the session cookie (usually when the users browser is setup to not accept cookies).

Comment: My next question would be: In what scenarios would the cookie be rejected?